# Formatting embedded XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a problem trying to format a list of values into XML. So far I can create my nodes and add values but the problem arises when one of these fields contains XML rather than a single value. I have a mock example below. 1 & 3  display correctly but 2 does not. I would ideally like to tab in the values of Value 2 to show they are all part of this value field but this is not as important as just formatting the XML into a readable format.

```
<FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name1</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>Value1<FieldValue>
</FieldValues>
<FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name2</FieldName>
    <FieldValue><Value2>2</Value2><List>1</List><ID>58</ID><FieldValue>
</FieldValues>    
<FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name3</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>Value3<FieldValue>
</FieldValues>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux [xmllint](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xmllint.htm) program is very useful for both checking the validity of XML and formatting it as follows:

```
$ xmllint --format data.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name1</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>Value1</FieldValue>
  </FieldValues>
  <FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name2</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>
      <Value2>2</Value2>
      <List>1</List>
      <ID>58</ID>
    </FieldValue>
  </FieldValues>
  <FieldValues>
    <FieldName>Name3</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>Value3</FieldValue>
  </FieldValues>
</data>
```

**NOTE:**

- The XML you submitted in your example, above, is not well formed.